# I want to use a field from a subclass from an array created in the SuperClass

Tags: java, arrays, subclass, superclass

I have an array of objects called _Array.  I have defined _Array[0] as object that is a subclass of the superclass.  I have fields in this sub class that dont exist in the superclass yet i want to access these fields from the array that i created in the superclass.  Is this possible?  There is sample code below.  I have indicated the line i'm having an issue with by the comment.

```
public class SuperClass {

    String color = "Red";
    int favenumber = 15;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SuperClass[] _Array = new SuperClass[10];

        _Array[0] = new SubClass(10, 150);

        _Array[0].age = 10;  /////THIS LINE HERE IS MY QUESTION

        System.out.println(_Array[0].getClass());
    }
}


public class SubClass extends SuperClass{

    public int age = 0;
    public int weight = 0;

    SubClass(int age, int weight)
    {
        this.age = age;
        this.weight = weight;        
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using some sort of `List` instead.

Comment: @Powerlord How would a list let him access a member from the derived class from an instance of the base class?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, but you could instead do this, if you are COMPLETELY SURE that the object is always a SubClass:

```
((SubClass) _Array[0]).age = 10;
```

This is casting the object first as SubClass and then accessing the field in one line. You could also check first if it is a SubClass:

```
if(_Array[0] instanceof SubClass){
    ((SubClass) _Array[0]).age = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to cast the object to the derived class, in your case:

```
((SubClass) _Array[0]).age = 10;
```

However, it's quite ugly:

- The code will throw an `InvalidCastException` if the object in that array isn't of type `SubClass`, and the compiler cannot help you catch this.
- The code is hard to understand.

Instead, you could first create a `SubClass` without immediately assigning it to the array, set the age as needed, and then add it to `_Array`:

```
SubClass s = new SubClass(10, 150);
_Array[0] = s;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but compiler should complain that the object doesn't have field named age because your array is declared as containing superclasses but at runtime array[0] will be instance of subclass which effectively has age, you just have to add something in order that code compiles you should cast array[0] to subclass. I advise you to read about object oriented programming and inheritance